# Issue sending SMTP mail from VMWorkstation using Powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, smtp, virtualization, vmware-workstation

I have the following script that I use to send an email when running a PowerShell program, and it works wonderfully well, usually:

```
$msg = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
        $msg.From = $from
        $msg.To.Add($to)
        $msg.Subject = $subject
        $msg.Body    = $html
        $msg.IsBodyHtml = $true

        $smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($server)
        $smtp.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
        try
        {
            $smtp.Send($msg)
            Write-Host "Email sent to $to without error"        
        } 
        catch 
        {
            $retryCount++           
            Write-Warning "Email failed to send. $_.Exception.Message" 
                     }
```

The issue is that I have since began to use this script in a VMWorkstation machine that I just set up, and I am unable to send the email at this point. Here is the error I'm getting:

```
WARNING: Email failed to send. Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client was not authent
icated".Exception.Message
```

I believe I am getting this error because I use:

```
$smtp.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
```

Is this the case? If so, is there a way I can pull my credential from my VM? I am using a bridged network, so I don't know why I couldn't access them with that call. I have also changed all the domain permissions to my corporate network.

Any insight would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PowerShell v2 or higher (and you should be), use [`Send-MailMessage`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx) instead.

```
Send-MailMessage -from $from -to $to -subject $subject -body $html -BodyAsHTML -smtphost $server -credential $(Get-Credential)
```

You'll be prompted to enter credentials for your SMTP server. If it's something you'll need repeatedly, you can prompt the user at the beginning of the script and store it:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
```

Then use `-credential $cred` in place of `-credential $(Get-Credential)`.

If the system you're running on is joined to your domain and you're logged in with a domain account, you should be able to skip the `-credential` parameter as it will default to the current user (you).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem I was having was due to the VM  not being connected to the corporate domain. Joining the corporate domain solved this issue.